# Kernel Module Time measuring

Tags: c, linux, kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to make a kernel module based on linked list and I want to measure the execution time of insertion of 1000 items into the list.

What header file and what function should I use to measure the starting time and the end time?

```c
    // start clock here
    for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    { 
         struct my_node* new = kmalloc(sizeof(struct my_node), GFP_KERNEL);
         new->data = i;
         list_add(&new->entry, &my_list);
    }
    // end clock here
    // print out the execution time in seconds here
```

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/timekeeping.html

Answer (score 0):

I provide you a link to a kernel module of mine where I solved the same task.

Here is the [GitHub project link](https://github.com/antonio-petricca/gpio-wire/tree/master/sources/transmitter/module) where you could look at the method `print_perf_data` to see how I collect performance data and print them calculating the elapsed time.

Regards.